# Generate secure random bytes in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I know that I can generate random bytes in Terraform easily enough:

```
resource "random_id" "foo" {
  byte_length = 32
}

resource "something_else" "foo" {
  secret = sensitive(random_id.foo.b64std)
}
```

However, the output of the `random_id` resource is not marked sensitive, and the value is exposed in logs as the resource `id`, even though its use in `something_else` is redacted by the `sensitive()` function.

I know that `random_password` is treated as secure, but it doesn't provide the ability to generate raw random bytes.

Is there a good way to generate a *secure* bunch of random bytes as a Terraform-managed resource?

(I'm aware that the value will always be visible in the state file, but we manage that already. I'm worried about output log files that will much more widely visible.)

**EDIT**: I found a [request to mark random_id secure](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-random/issues/66) but the idea was rejected as outside the intended use.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the base64encode function instead? Unfortunately Terraform doesn't support this yet(see link I posted below). Something like this might give you some ideas you could use -

```
resource "random_string" "this" {
length = 32
}

output "random_string_output" {
value = "'${base64encode(random_string.this.result)}'"
}
```

[This GitHub issue talks about this limitation/workaround quite a bit](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-random/issues/63)

Comment: Assuming you meant `random_password` since that is actually marked as sensitive. However it's encoded, this is still a string with limited character set rather than truly random bytes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such resource or data source in terraform. But you could develop your own [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) that would produce those "truly random bytes" to your satisfaction.